# how to use ruby to make hash tags into html links

Tags: ruby

Given a string with hash tags, how do I arrive to a new string with all the hash tags wrapped with html anchor tags?

I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: the "i have no idea how to do it" i added after it said my question doesn't meet the quality standard, I tried, but not working, kind of clumsy too. I set up a method return all the tags in an array, then try to iterate through the tags and string.sub(tag, html_tag).

Comment: Consider learning regular expressions in Ruby (plenty of helpful tutorials online, e.g. http://strugglingwithruby.blogspot.com/2009/05/regular-expressions-in-ruby.html). Regexes allow you to match a string with some pattern and optionally replace the matches.

Comment: What does this even mean? Is this a Twitter thing? How about example inputs / outputs? Can you put more than 15 seconds of effort into this?

Answer (score 2):

use `twitter-text` gem to extract hashes and link them

https://github.com/twitter/twitter-text-rb

`auto_link_hashtags` method is what your ar looking for they have mnay more have a look

Example from rails console after including the gem in project

```
1.9.3p194 :004 > include Twitter::Autolink
 => Object 

1.9.3p194 :007 > auto_link_hashtags " #goohh" , :hashtag_url_base => "http://xyzzcac.com/hash/"
 #=> " <a class=\"tweet-url hashtag\" href=\"http://xyzzcac.com/hash/goohh\" rel=\"nofollow\" title=\"#goohh\">#goohh</a>"
```